# Rxjs Custom Subject complete and dispose worker

Tags: rxjs, web-worker

I'm wondering if exists a better way to complete a worker subject. To do this, a complete when all tasks have run.

Here is the code:

```
export class WorkerSubject<T> extends Subject<T> {

  protected worker: Worker;

  protected jobs = 0;

  protected finish = false;

  constructor(callback: Function, async = false) {
    super();
    this.worker =
      async ? createWorkerPostMessage(callback) : createStaticWorker(callback);
    this.worker.onmessage = e => {
      this.jobs--;
      super.next(e.data);
      if (this.jobs === 0 && this.finish) {
        super.complete();
        this.worker.terminate();
      }
    };
    this.worker.onerror = e => {
      super.error(e);
      this.worker.terminate();
    };
  }

  next(value: any): void {
    if (this.finish) {
       throw new Error('WorkerSubject complete, no more values can be emited.')
    }
    this.jobs++;
    this.worker.postMessage(value);
  }

  complete() {
    this.finish = true;
  }
}
```

Any idea to improve this?

Comment: What's the problem with your current code?

Comment: Complete is not executed while worker has not finished... I doubt if I doing something wrong or there is a better way to do this